# htaccess rule not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I have [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) installed on `www.marcou.it/wp`, and I would set it as the default directory. So if I type `marcou.it`, the browser has to show me WordPress.

I have set these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On #Created by aruba. Do not touch this file!
#ATTENTION: Remove file index.(php|html|htm)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wp/$1 [L]
```

But if I go on `www.marcou.it`, I get this returned:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /wp/index.htm was not found on this server.

What is the problem?

Comment: I would recommend just moving your WordPress install to the root rather than doing it with rewrites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On #created by aruba do not touch this file!
#ATTENTION: Remove file index.(php|html|htm)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wp/ [L]

# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect anything not in the `/wp/` subdirectory, you can use the following to redirect to this directly, and then drop the `index.htm` if necessary. The `index.htm` is likely being appended as the default document.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^((?!wp/).*) wp/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^wp/index.htm$ wp/ [R,L]
```

You can test these rules (make sure your test url includes the "http://") here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: this work but I won't to remove /wp/ from url

Comment: The `[R]` rule is telling it to redirect, remove it and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the code that you've mentioned on this question, for it's not right, and try this one, in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp/?
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1
```

---

Now try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/? /wp
RewriteRule ^(.+)? /wp/$1
```

If that didn't work, try to remove the `Options +FollowSymlinks` and check again!

Comment: not working...............

Comment: What is the name of the folder where your `index` is located?

Comment: Also, check my updates!